# C#: how to explicitly set culture for Double.Parse(string num)

Tags: c#, parsing, culture

I download one program that read file and then parse double values from String to Double. But I get an exception because this file contains numbers with '.' separator, but there is ',' in my culture. How can I set culture explicitly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would use the `Parse` overload that accepts an `IformatProvider`.

```
Double.Parse("23.56", new CultureInfo("..."))
```

If you don't know the culture used to write the file you create a `NumberFormatInfo` and configure it as you like:

```
var nfi = new NumberFormatInfo();

nfi.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";

var d = Double.Parse("23.56", nfi);
```

Comment: This seperator removed the comma for me, and added no dot instead. What did I do wrong? (Talking about the `var nfi` solution)

Comment: @Robuust, the default constructor for `NumberFormatInfo` is based on the invariant culture so it already uses dot as the decimal separator. On the sample above, which as is should parse the number as intended, I only reset the property to illustrate that it is writable and that you can configure it as you wish. It is probably best for you to create a new question providing detailed information about the problem you're facing.

Answer (score 2):

this was i'm used to do but i think i will use the NumberFormatInfo in the future !

```
CultureInfo oldCulture = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-US");

try
{
   if (Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture != null) 
   {
     double d = Double.Parse("23.5");
   }
}
finally
{
   Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oldCulture;
}
```

Comment: You might find this bit of wisdom from Raymond Chen interesting: [Don't use global state to manage a local problem](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/12/11/9193695.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Also usable:

```
double.Parse((""+s).Replace(",","."), System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Ugly as hell, but that's .Net... :)